# Return outputs of a function to a dictionary

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a function which can return a variable number of outputs. I would like to save this to a dictionary like so:

```
val_dict={}
idx = 0

for key in some_test_function(1,2,3):
    val_dict[idx] = key
    idx +=1
```

Now while this thing does work, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to add the indices in the dictionary:

```
val_dict = dict(enumerate(some_test_function(1, 2, 3)))
```

This gives you the exact same integer index to value mapping. However, just a list would give you the exact same index-to-value mapping:

```
val_list = list(some_test_function(1, 2, 3))
```

(if `some_test_function` already returns a `list` object, just remove the `list()` call).